# Proving question

Tags: geometry

> Triangle $ABC$ has vertices at $A(-2,-1)$, $B(4,6)$ and $C(6,-3)$
>
> Prove that it is isosceles.

In order to prove that is is isosceles

1. Find distance of $AB$，$BC$, and $AC$. Two of them will have the same length.(I know how to do it)
2. Find the three angles. (I don't know how to)

Comment: You have to think about slopes.

Comment: Draw it on graph paper and then ?

Comment: Jack. 3 sides given, you can use the cosine rule.

Comment: Thanks for the information, immediately understand